# Filter dataframe by year, then count frequency of binary states between value intervals

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this (this shows the bottom 6 entries):

```
            Imax        SzT 
date                            
2017-09-14  10.139999   0.0 
2017-09-15  0.000000    0.0 
2017-09-16  0.000000    0.0 
2017-09-17  0.000000    0.0 
2017-09-18  0.200000    0.0
2017-09-19  12.710000   1.0
```

This dataframe extends back to 1998 and shows the date, the maximum rainfall intensity of that date (Imax), and whether or not a flood occurred (SzT, either 0 or 1).

I wish to 1) break this down by year, 2) count the frequency of rainfall intensity between various intervals (e.g. 0 - 2.5mm/hr, 2.5 - 5mm/hr, and so on), and then 3) produce a count of the number of flood events that occur (or not) in these intervals. My thoughts of an outcome look a little bit like this:

```
             2015
interval     no flood    flood     
0 - 2.5      27          1
2.5 - 5      15          1
5 - 10       7           4
10 - 15      3           3
15 - 20      1           3

             2016
interval     no flood    flood     
0 - 2.5      24          0
2.5 - 5      17          0
5 - 10       6           2
10 - 15      6           1
15 - 20      3           2

             2017
interval     no flood    flood     
0 - 2.5      32          0
2.5 - 5      19          0
5 - 10       9           0
10 - 15      4           0
15 - 20      2           1
```

My ultimate aim is to calculate the frequentist probability of a flood in a given year for a given rainfall intensity interval and show how this is changing through time.

The method I have so far thought of to split this dataframe up so far is very cumbersome, involving adding a column for the year 'Y', masking the df by value of 'Y' to create individual dataframes for each year, then applying further masks to each of those dfs to determine the frequency between each interval... Please, anybody, help!

I hope that makes sense and thanks a big bunch in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using pandas without custom-written helper functions is to `pd.cut` the `Imax` column into a new column of data type `category`, then to `groupby` your other criteria:

```
# Simplified example data; read with df = pd.read_clipboard()

            Imax        SzT 
date                            
2017-09-14  10.139999   1.0 
2017-09-15  0.000000    0.0 
2017-09-16  0.000000    0.0 
2017-09-17  0.000000    0.0 
2017-09-18  0.200000    0.0
2017-09-19  12.710000   1.0
2016-03-01  3           0
2016-05-10  6           0
2016-09-20  12          1
2016-09-20  14          1
2015-03-01  0           0
2015-03-02  6           0
2015-04-15  19          1
2015-05-20  13          0

# Ensure index is a DatetimeIndex
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# Cut float column into category column
df['interval'] = pd.cut(df['Imax'], bins=bins, right=False)

# Group by year, interval, and flood flag
(df.groupby([df.index.year, 'interval', 'SzT'])
   .size()
   .unstack()
   .fillna(0)
   .astype(int)
   .rename({0: 'no flood', 1: 'flood'}, axis=1))

SzT                no flood  flood
date interval                     
2015 [0.0, 2.5)           1      0
     [5.0, 10.0)          1      0
     [10.0, 15.0)         1      0
     [15.0, 20.0)         0      1
2016 [2.5, 5.0)           1      0
     [5.0, 10.0)          1      0
     [10.0, 15.0)         0      2
2017 [0.0, 2.5)           4      0
     [10.0, 15.0)         0      2
```

Comment: How are you people so clever? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use groupby, here is one way to do it:

Started with creating some random data to play with:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = pd.date_range(start='01/01/2000', end='01/01/2010')
df['Imax'] = [random.randint(0,200)/10 for x in range(df.shape[0])]
df['SzT'] = [random.randint(0,1) for x in range(df.shape[0])]
```

then created a function to convert values to intervals:

```
intervals = list(zip([x/2 for x in list(range(0,40,5))], [x/2 for x in list(range(5,45,5))]))

def to_interval(x):
    for i in intervals:
        if i[0]<=x<i[1]:
            return i
```

then added interval and year column:

```
df['interval'] = [to_interval(x) for x in df.Imax.values]
df['year'] = [x.year for x in df.date]
```

then grouped to get sum(num of flood days) and count:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['year', 'interval'])
result = grouped.agg({'SzT':['count', 'sum']})
```

then subtracted sum from count to get num of no flood days:

```
 result['SzT', 'count_minus_sum'] = result['SzT', 'count'] - result['SzT', 'sum']
```

Comment: I repeat my comment from above, how are you people so clever? Thank you!